# Deleting Rails 3 subdomain cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I've run into some problems with users having multiple session cookies from my domain.

in session_store we did *not* use `domain: :all` initially.

So, users would sometimes end up with cookies for domain `example.com` and `www.example.com`

For out site, subdomain-specific cookies do not matter.  I just want one cookie for the whole site.

If I just change session_store to add `domain: all`, it doesn't necessarily mean the existing cookies go away.  In fact, the user will probably now have a third cookie and now have one for `example.com`, `www.example.com` and `.example.com`

Given the way the cookies RFC is written and how Rack implements handling cookies, the wrong, old cookie could be loaded when the user request is made.  [It just loads up the 'first' one in the cookie string from the header.](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L308)

So...Does anyone know of a reliable way to delete old cookies from a user's browser.  Specifically I want to delete the cookies from domains `www.example.com` and `example.com`, while leaving the cookie from `.example.com` in-tact.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prevent other `domain: :all` cookies intact, I believe the simplest way is to directly add a `Set-Cookie` header from the server to expire it.

```rb
# When you believe the client is sending a cookie with `Domain=www.example.com` or `Domain=example.com`, instead of `Domain=.example.com`
response.set_header('Set-Cookie', '_my_app_session=expiring; Path=/; Max-Age=0; HttpOnly')

# For Rails < 5 (not tested)
headers['Set-Cookie'] = '_my_app_session=expiring; Path=/; Max-Age=0; HttpOnly'
```

My other attempts:

1. `reset_sesion` won't work because it will use `Domain=.example.com` according to the `domain: :all` setting
2. I also wanted to expire it from client-side, but the `HttpOnly` attributes (rails' default) prevent js from manipulating these cookies.
3. Waiting for the 'Session' cookie to expire may take longer than you think, since most browser just actually won't expire it after restart ([ref](https://makandracards.com/makandra/28275-psa-chrome-and-firefox-do-not-always-clear-session-cookies-on-exit))

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the key to store your session?

```html
YourApplication.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_new_session_key', domain: :all,  tld_length: 2
```